# How to remotely create a file in a Kubernetes container?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh

I have a pod named `nginx` which has two containers named `nginx` and `busybox`.  To create a file inside the `busybox` container, I have to do:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx -c busybox -- bin/sh
# echo sometext > /temp/testfile
# exit
```

I want to simplify it into a one-liner, so I try:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx -c busybox -- echo sometext > /temp/testfile
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
bash: /temp/testfile: No such file or directory
```

Putting `echo sometext > /temp/testfile` between double quotes yields this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "echo sometext > /temp/testfile": stat echo sometext > /temp/testfile: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Why is it not working?  Is there any way to make such one-liner?

Comment: Remember that it does occasionally happen that a Kubernetes Pod gets destroyed outside your control; maybe a node has too many Pods running on it, or too few and a cluster autoscaler is being taken out of service.  In these cases anything you do with `kubectl exec` will be lost.  Do you want to add this file into a Docker image instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
kubectl exec -it nginx -c busybox -- sh -c "echo sometext > /temp/testfile"
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you so much!  Why is `sh -c` required here while things like `cat` or `ls -l` don't need it?